# How to use x2 canvas elements and rendering paper.js on img capture of html5 video to base64

Tags: html5-canvas, base64, html5-video, video-capture, paperjs

Still very much a newbie to coding, so please be gentle :)

I'm hoping someone might be able to help how to use Paper.js on a second canvas after the first one has been executed?

I'm trying to use x2 canvas elements:

- Canvas 1 - to capture a html5 video image still and convert to base64 (tick :-) = done)

  Canvas 2 - Use the base64 image and perform the 'Working with Rasters to find the colors of pixels' and convert to circle paths (boo = fail :-( )

Something like this:

[image: color of pixels render]

The code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>

    <video id="video" preload="auto" muted="" playsinline="" width="580" src="blob:https://www.georgefisher.co.uk/78e3a45c-ae07-4ea5-af56-45a5ed9cf1b0"></video>
    <script>
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
      var videoSrc = 'https://camsecure.co/HLS/georgefisher.m3u8';
      if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
      }

      else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
        video.src = videoSrc;
      }
      video.play()
    </script>

<br>
<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="overflow:auto">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" resize>
  <img src="" id="myImg"/></canvas>
```

```
var resultb64="";

function capture() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');     
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
  
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth/4;
  
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight/4;
  
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth/4, video.videoHeight/4);
  
    resultb64=canvas.toDataURL();
    document.querySelector("#myImg").src = canvas.toDataURL();
}

  /*Paper JS Setup for working in CodePen */
  /* ====================== *
   *  0. Initiate Canvas    *
   * ====================== */
  
  // expose paperjs classes into global scope
  paper.install(window);
  
  // Only executed our code once the DOM is ready.
  window.onload = function() {
    // bind paper to the canvas
    paper.setup('canvas2');
    // paper.activate();
  
    // Get a reference to the canvas object
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // console.log(ctx, image);
    // ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    // return;
  
    // }
    
  // Create a raster item using the image id='' tag

  var image = document.querySelector('img');
  var raster = new Raster(image);
  
  // Hide the raster:
  raster.visible = false;
  
  // The size of our grid cells:
  var gridSize = 15;
  
  // Space the cells by 120%:
  var spacing = 1
  ;
  
  // As the web is asynchronous, we need to wait for the raster to load before we can perform any operation on its pixels.
  raster.onLoad = function() {
  
    // Since the example image we're using is much too large, and therefore has way too many pixels, lets downsize it to 40 pixels wide and 30 pixels high:
    raster.size = new Size(40, 30);
  
    for (var y = 0; y < raster.height; y++) {
      for(var x = 0; x < raster.width; x++) {
        // Get the color of the pixel:
        var color = raster.getPixel(x, y);
  
        // Create a circle shaped path:
        var path = new Path.Circle({
          center: new Point(x, y).multiply(gridSize),
          radius: gridSize / 2 / spacing,
  
        });
  
  // Set the fill color of the path to the color
              // of the pixel:
              path.fillColor = color;
      }
    }
  
    // Move the active layer to the center of the view, so all the created paths in it appear centered.
    project.activeLayer.position = view.center;
  
  }
  }
```

I've tried giving the second canvas a different Id="canvas2" and referencing that, which I can see in the console. However, nothing appears in the second canvas and the paper.js script doesn't seem to execute, can someone help me understand why?

Please see also see link to the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmnes/o4Lpkfs6/1/

Answer (score 2):

### Alternatives method.

You don't need to capture the video, you don't need to capture the pixels using paper.js and raster. You don't need to find the color of each circle and draw it.

All these methods are slow, complex, and power hungry.

You can create a mask and mask out the circles, with the colors drawn from a smaller canvas with a res that matches the number off circles.

### How to

- Add one (main canvas) canvas to the DOM. This will display the result
- Create 2 offscreen canvas.

  - One (color canvas) has the same resolution as the circles you want to display. Eg if you have 30 by 40 circle the canvas res should be 30 by 40
  - One (mask canvas) is the circle mask. It is the same resolution as the main canvas. Draw the circles all in one color on this canvas.

Then rendering once a frame

- Draw the video on the color canvas to fit.
- Turn off smoothing on the main canvas eg `ctxMain.imageSmoothingEnabled = false`
- Draw the color canvas onto the main canvas to fit.

  This will draw a color square at each circle position. `ctx.drawImage(colorCanvas, 0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height)`
- Set composite operation `"destination-in"` eg `ctxMain.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"`
- Draw the mask canvas (canvas with circles on it) onto the main canvas. This will remove pixels outside each circle.
- Restore default composite operation for the main canvas `ctxMain.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"`

All done for a real-time FX on almost any device.

The above methods is the fastest way to render the effect you are after using the 2D API

Comment: Another contender would be to use a CanvasPattern fill mode instead of a second canvas for the mask. I honestly don't know which would be the most performant and I suspect the results would be different on different devices, but I'd assume low memory devices would get some improvements on large canvas resolution.

Comment: Oh and for the "fastest way", you could use WebCodecs where available instead of an HTMLMediaElement to render the video on the canvas.

Comment: Thinking of it a bit more but neither the CanvasPattern nor the mask canvas are necessary, fill a simple Path2d on the main canvas would be enough.